# Cannot enable Slack for Bluemix DevOps services beta

Tags: ibm-cloud, devops, slack

I wanted to take advantage of the Slack communications beta for Bluemix DevOps services, but in my IBM restricted DevOps project I do not see any option to enable it..

What am I missing?

Comment: Could you please be more detailed in your question? What type of stack do you want to build?

Comment: I think you mean slack rather than stack?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is explained at [Integrating Slack with Bluemix DevOps Services BETA - Integrations - IBM Bluemix DevOps Services](https://beta3.hub.jazz.net/docs/integrations/slack_auto/):

Project's `Overview` page->`Integrated Tools` section->`Integrate with a tool`->`SLACK`.

Comment: Apparently the feature was not enabled until later in the day. All set!

Answer (score 0):

You may want to instead use the next evolution of Bluemix DevOps Services, which has Slack integration, in addition to several other ones.
Please see https://developer.ibm.com/devops-services/2016/06/16/open-toolchain-with-ibm-bluemix-devops-services/

Comment: it's best to add the critical bits of a link to your answer, instead of just dropping a link